# Associate a directory with my app in internal storage

Tags: android

I do not actually know what this is called. But I have seen app icons beside their directories in internal storage. I assume that it's some kind of association. I would like to know how to achieve this for a directory made by my app.

Here is a screenshot showing Telegram and WhatsApp doing what I want:

[image]

I am using the following to create a directory:

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp").mkdirs()
```

What else should I add to the above code?

Comment: It's probably based on the file manager you're using and not to do with the metadata of your app.

Comment: No. Because I have seen it all file managers I have used. Even some lesser known apps like ADM have app icons beside their directories.

Answer (score 1):

> What else should I add to the above code?

Nothing. And note that this code does not work on Android 10 (by default) or Android R+ (for all apps), as [external storage has been locked down](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

> But I have seen app icons beside their directories in internal storage.

Note that from an Android SDK standpoint, you are looking at [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). More importantly, you are looking at external storage through some app.

> I would like to know how to achieve this for a directory made by my app.

There is nothing in Android directly for this. You will need to talk to the developers of the app that you used (where you see this icon) and ask what they are doing. It could be as simple as "see if there is an installed app with the same name as the directory" or "see if there is an installed launcher icon with the same name as the directory".

> Because I have seen it all file managers I have used

That means that you have more people that you can contact to see what they are doing. Again, there is nothing in the OS for this. After all, if there were, I could write an app to associate my app icon with every directory, and others could do the same. Whatever these file managers are doing, hopefully it is based on information that apps cannot manipulate to somehow spam the association information.

Comment: Nice answer. The article is enlightening. But I honestly hope Google change mind on forcing scoped storage. My app is rather complicated. Many other libraries will simply break. Here is another article from XDA developers: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-storage-access-framework-scoped-storage/

Comment: @SayantanRoychowdhury: ...and [here is my reply to that post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/05/storage-access-framework-counterpoints.html), from back in June.